# Why Facebook is not getting the title and the image when sharing the URL?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, cloudflare

Normally, when we paste a URL (example : http://techhamlet.com/2012/03/ipad-drop-test/) of a post, facebook scans and takes the title, description and the image from the post. This worked in my site for a long time. I also have og: meta tags in place... But recently it stopped taking those info! First it took nearly two hours for FB to work like that. Now nothing...

Im using wordpress and also have Cloud Flare. Disabled cloudflare to see whether its blocking Facebook or not... Still its not working! Can you please help?

Comment: Use the debugger at developers.facebook.com/tools/debug on your URL and see what metadata is being detected

Comment: @Igy Thanks my friend... I just checked it... It gave me an Response Code: 503! But my site is working!

Comment: You probably have some code which is failing when the debugger makes its requests - a user agent check, code that's not aware of the 'Range:' header or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open bug with Facebook about this issue (the debugger is intermittently returning 503 response codes). Please [contact us](http://support.cloudflare.com/cgi/discussion/new) so we can keep track of this issue.

CloudFlare isn't blocking Facebook or vice versa.

Comment: Yep.. its a problem with cloudflare! I reported it to them and temporarily disable cloudflare and now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing Cloudflare entirely seems to fix this. Just disabling Cloudflare temporarily (i.e. entering developer mode) doesn’t seem to. It’s very annoying, but the only fix at this stage, if it is important enough to warrant it, seems to be to not use Cloudflare.

Cloudflare have advised me that it is not an issue with their systems, however in my own testing I have not had a problem without Cloudflare. Introduce Cloudflare to the mix, and the 503 errors start to pile up.

Edit: As of 18 April 2012 Cloudflare advise me that this has been fixed, and I can no longer replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There still seems to be issues with this: I have just added a site that's using WordPress to cloudflare and the same behaviour is displayed. Bypassing cloudflare fixes the issue.